# problem with RMarkdown on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: pdf, latex

I am new to RStudio and RMarkdown. When I've tried to knit my first pdf document in Rstudio, I got the following message:

```
processing file: Preview-4cef6f7763df.Rmd
  |.............                                                    |  20%
  ordinary text without R code

  |..........................                                       |  40%
label: unnamed-chunk-1
  |.......................................                          |  60%
  ordinary text without R code

  |....................................................             |  80%
label: unnamed-chunk-2 (with options) 
List of 1
 $ echo: logi FALSE

cropping ./Preview-4cef6f7763df_files/figure-latex/unnamed-chunk-2-1.pdf
PDFCROP 1.38, 2012/11/02 - Copyright (c) 2002-2012 by Heiko Oberdiek.
==> 1 page written on `./Preview-4cef6f7763df_files/figure-latex/unnamed-chunk-2-1.pdf'.
  |.................................................................| 100%
  ordinary text without R code


/usr/lib/rstudio/bin/pandoc/pandoc Preview-4cef6f7763df.utf8.md --to latex --from markdown+autolink_bare_uris+ascii_identifiers+tex_math_single_backslash-implicit_figures --output Preview-4cef6f7763df.pdf --template /home/klemen/R/i686-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.0/rmarkdown/rmd/latex/default.tex --highlight-style tango --latex-engine pdflatex --variable 'geometry:margin=1in' 
output file: Preview-4cef6f7763df.knit.md

! Incomplete \iffalse; all text was ignored after line 110.
<inserted text> 
                \fi 
<*> /tmp/tex2pdf.2746/input.tex

!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
Transcript written on /tmp/tex2pdf.2746/input.log.

pandoc: Error producing PDF from TeX source
Error: pandoc document conversion failed with error 43
Execution halted
```

I really don't know how to fix this. Can anyone help? Thanks.

Comment: I get the same error on Mac OSX 10.9.5 with rmarkdown 0.7, RStudio 0.99.441 and R version 3.2.0 (2015-04-16) using the Full TeX Live 2015 Distribution (MacTeX Distribution). Previously I was using the TeX Live 2012 version and had the same error (the update didn't help).
I just tried to knit the standard example file you get when you create a new .Rmd file.

Answer (score 2):

Removing the dot in the date (or escaping it with `\\.`) resolved the error in my case.

See: https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/issues/145